# How to calculate MD5 checksum of blob using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, md5sum

My requirement is to upload large files (upto 50GB) through browser. So I used [JQuery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload those large files in smaller chunks.

Now I have to calculate MD5 checksum for each chunk to avoid data corruption issues from browser to server.

Is there any plugin in JQuery to calculate checksum for the blob chunks except Google CryptoJS utility ?

Comment: maby try jQuery.md5(string)? (http://helpcenter.epages.com/Doc/ver_6_12_3/epages/jQuery/api-jQuery.md5.html)

Comment: or just use google: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+md5+of+file

Comment: I'm sure you can use any MD5 implementation. Calculating a hash is not particularly subject to cross-browser issues.

Comment: Why the jQuery requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [js-md5](https://github.com/emn178/js-md5).

This is a online [demo](http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/md5_checksum.html) to get file checksum.

You can input arraybuffer like this

```
var total; // total file size
var batch = 1024 * 1024; // batch size
var start = 0;
var current = md5;
var asyncUpdate = function () {
  if (start < total) {
    var end = Math.min(start + batch, total);
    current = current.update(arrayBuffer.slice(start, end));
    start = end;
    setTimeout(asyncUpdate);
  } else {
    var hash = current.hex(); // result
  }
}
asyncUpdate();
```